"help" command doesn't exist pycord
When I type /help, I get this error:
 "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "help" is not found"

@bot.slash_command(name="help", description="Get help via a helpful video!")
async def help_command(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
    user_mention = ctx.author.mention
    help_embed = discord.Embed(title="Help Video",
                               description=f"{user_mention}, here is the help video you requested:",
                               color=discord.Color.blue())
    help_embed.add_field(
        name="Watch Video",
        value="[Click here to watch](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/993834541103976449/1193685361369563176/SPOILER_JOSH-1.mp4)",
        inline=False
    )
    await ctx.respond(embed=help_embed)

When I do /help command, it should mention the user and send the video.

You should Google it before asking on forums, and read PyCord's documentation a bit:
https://guide.pycord.dev/extensions/commands/help-command
Anyways, if you really want a slash command like annother, you can do:
bot = commands.Bot(any_parameter_here, help_command=None)

And then define the command as you want. However, this is not recommanded by the PyCord documentation, read it with the link I put to get other answers.

The point of making an answer here is not just to link it to docs, it's to actually answer it

@BlueRobin OK, so no one is gonna answer the question I guess ? Just because "it's a dumb question" no one will ever answer ? People learn for mistakes, and not telling them their mistake will make they will forever do the same mistake without knowing what it is.

You were a little condescending by saying "You should Google." If anything, I'm saying that should've at least been in the comments. (Although I will say I was a little hasty in reading your answer but I believe you should still expand on "read it with the link I put to get other answers")
